# How to edit or remove Gmail reservation Highlights?

Tags: google-schemas

I'm looking for information on how to edit/remove the information that Gmail highlights at the top of a reservation email.

We run [www.bikemorzine.com](http://www.bikemorzine.com) a MTB Holiday company and whenever we send out a reservation to a client Gmail is highlighting information from this reservation at the top of the email. This would be fine however some of this information is incorrect, for example it sends our head office address rather than the accommodation address for the holiday etc which can cause a lot of confusion.

How can I edit or completely remove this highlight feature?
image below of the highlight at the top of our automated booking emails.

Thanks in advance.

[Gmail Highlights issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzPIR.png)

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (and in fact, all of the Stack Exchange Network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which require users to go off-site to get more information are not useful to future visitors, particularly once the off-site resource changes. This question might be good/useful, but you need to move enough code into the question so we know what you're asking without needing to go off-site to find out. Please see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428) for more details.